# optimum way to insert values into sqlite DB

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

the below method is to insert records to sqlite database table, and i know that this method wil be called numerous times from inside loops.

my question is, is the code below the optimum way to insert values into DB table?or there could be a better approach as the time and performance matter.

kindly please advice.

**code**:

```
public void insertValues(String name, int age, String address, String gender) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Connection conn = getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("insert into "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+COL_1+", "+COL_2+", "+COL_3+", "+COL_4+") values (?, ?, ?, ?)");

    ps.setString(1, name);
    ps.setLong(2, age);
    ps.setString(3, address);
    ps.setString(4, gender);

    ps.addBatch();
    ps.executeBatch();

    ps.close();
    conn.close();
}
```

Comment: You are not using batch properly. Either you pass multiple values and prepare batch and execute it once. Now you are adding single query in batch and executing it.

Comment: @NamanGala kindly please, would u provide an example.

Comment: Instead of passing single name, age, address, gender, pass list of dto. And in that dto you can set this 4 values. Then iterate that list in your method and do addBatch in iteration and after that iteration is over you can call executeBatch.

Comment: @NamanGala what is dto??

Comment: dto is data transfer object. It is simple pojo (plain old java object) with attributes (name, age, address, gender) and getter and setter

Comment: @NamanGala what if i kept the same methods posted above without "ps.executeBatch();" and created anothe method "ExecBatch(PreparedStatement ps)" that will be called after the loop ends

Comment: Yes that will do. In that case you will require a preparedStatement, a method/loop that will set values in preparedStatement and do addBatch and then you can cal executeBatch. **Note:** You have to create prepatedStatement only once.

Comment: @rmaik execute batch is used when you have to insert lots of statements.For example for(int i=0;i<100 ..... insert into tables().....) but your query is inserting single record so need to use batch

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095176/optimizing-batch-inserts-sqlite

Answer (score 1):

You should use connection pool, rather than opening new connection for each insert. Creating brand new connection for each query adds significant overhead- in most cases opening connection will take longer than actual query execution.

If you are using Spring, consider using Spring Boot, then see http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database for details.

Spring boot will auto-configure connection pool for you- you just need to add jars to classpath. For detailed tutorial, see
https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/
JdbcTemplate offers good way to access SQL databases (you may also consider Spring Data, it is even easier).

Comment: would u please provide an example for that?

Comment: i am using sqlite java

Comment: i am using java not android, can i still use Spring connection pool?

Comment: I recoment Spring for every non-trivial java project (non-trivial=more than 500 lines of production code). Samples I have provided targed Java SE (not Android) so they are definetly good for you.